# куки в laravel записать

Tags: laravel, laravel5

как записать в куки в ларавель?

```
Cookie::put('referal', $username, 60);
```

но пишет

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Cookie' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

при переходе по реф ссылке я примаю в контроллере

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function  index(){
        return view('home');
    }
    public function referal(User $user, $username)
    {
        Cookie::put('referal', $username, 60);
        $name = Cookie::get('name');
        dd($name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

сделал так

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar;


class IndexController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function  index(Request $request){
        $value = $request->cookie('referrer');
        return view('home');
    }
    public function referal(CookieJar $cookieJar, $username)
    {
        if($username){
            $cookieJar->queue(cookie('referrer', $username, 45000));
        }
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```